# Why doesn't Web Forms for Marketers correctly populate the selected DropList value in my custom save action?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Inside my custom save action, I iterate through the form fields (the `AdaptedControlResult` objects).  Any form field which is a DropList (from any source -- manually entered values, or an item lookup) is returning a string value of `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``

Now, it's important to know, *it's not returning an actual List*.  It's returning a *literal string* with that value.

So, this call:

```
fields.GetEntryByName("MyFieldName").Value
```

Is returning the string: `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``.  Not the value of the dropdown.  A string saying that's it's a `List<string>`.

I have confirmed the HTML of the form is rendering correctly.  I have manually checked the inbound `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` values as well...

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["BGWnjkQqrE6w6sr31IgzrQ.Sections[5].Fields[0].Value"]
```

That is the correctly-selected value of the drop down (a Sitecore ID).

So, the data is getting output to the form correctly, and the inbound `Request.Form` data is also correct.  Somewhere, Sitecore is deciding not to populate the selected value into the `AdaptedControlResult` object.

What's additionally odd is that for DropList field types, the selected value *does* appear in the `Parameters` property (inexplicably).  I would just detect this and use it, but it's not consistent -- for instance, for textbox field types, the word "multiline" appears there.

All other field types work fine -- I have several text entry fields, and some radio button lists.  It's just DropList fields.

What is the trick to getting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in Sitecore when using the WFFM module in MVC. You can find more details in this Knowledge Base Article - [Incorrect data is saved for list fields in WFFM MVC](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/311218).

The fix is listed on the kb article and depends on the exact version of Sitecore you are using. Sorry to provided a link only answer but there are multiple steps reqiured for the fix and the download for the fix is attached in the article.